# how to add sub groups to an existing group in keyclaok :getting 404 not found

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-admin-cli

using keyclaok rest api i have easyliy created a group now i wanted to add a subGroup to it for that the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_updategroup) said the rest api lacks to add sub gropups to an exisitng group after some research i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887180/keycloak-how-to-programmatically-add-new-subgroups-with-associated-users)

here is my code

```
val keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder() //
                .serverUrl(baseUrl) //
                .realm("master") //
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD) //
                .clientId("admin-cli") //
                .username("3a3ee740-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx") //
                .password("admin") //
                .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
                .build();
             
              val realm = keycloak.realm("demo")

              val subgroup = new GroupRepresentation
              subgroup.setName("childGroup")
              subgroup.setPath("/parent/child")

              val response = realm.groups().group(parentGroupID).subGroup(subgroup)
```

here is the exception i am getting

```
Javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:603)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:149)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.subGroup(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.lufz.authentication.controllers.AdminController.$anonfun$createSubGroupViaJavaAdminApi$4(AdminController.scala:943)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.ApplyConverterInstances$$anon$1.$anonfun$apply$1(ApplyConverterInstances.scala:14)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$2.$anonfun$apply$3(Directive.scala:234)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResult$2(BasicDirectives.scala:68)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives.$anonfun$onComplete$3(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.$anonfun$transformWith$1(FastFuture.scala:36)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:40)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension(FastFuture.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension(FastFuture.scala:36)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives.$anonfun$onComplete$2(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:161)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResult$2(BasicDirectives.scala:68)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:161)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRequestContext$2(BasicDirectives.scala:45)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:161)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRequestContext$2(BasicDirectives.scala:45)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:161)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$2(RouteConcatenation.scala:47)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:40)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension(FastFuture.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:25)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives.$anonfun$handleExceptions$2(ExecutionDirectives.scala:32)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$2(RouteConcatenation.scala:47)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:40)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension(FastFuture.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:25)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResultWith$2(BasicDirectives.scala:74)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:161)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives.$anonfun$handleExceptions$2(ExecutionDirectives.scala:32)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$.$anonfun$createAsyncHandler$1(Route.scala:110)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$31.onPush(Ops.scala:1400)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:541)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:423)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:625)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:502)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:600)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:769)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:784)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:691)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:225)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:151)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.grantToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:90)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:70)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:65)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:590)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

the exception was on this line

```
val response = realm.groups().group(parentGroupID).subGroup(subgroup)
```

note: parent group already exists in keycloak

Comment: Are you sure parentGroupID is set correctly?

Comment: how can i set the parentgroupid as the parent group was created via rest api